# How to create date object from string retrieved from JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, date

I would like to create a new Javascript date object and save it to a variable all from a JSON endpoint route. The JSON looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "class_instructor": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "location": "Boise",
    "start_date_time": "Thu, 19 Nov 2020 09:10:00 GMT"
  },
  {
    "class_instructor": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "location": "Meridian",
    "start_date_time": "Mon, 16 Nov 2020 09:10:00 GMT"
  }
]
```

I have been able to grab each objects value through iteration using Axios and saving it to a variable, however I would like to generate a javascript date object from the `start_date_time` value's strings. I am sure I can grab each of character of the string and eventually create the date object by individually adding each year, month, day... `let this_date = new Date(2020, 11, 19, 9, 10)`

However, this doesn't appear to be fullproof and there has got to be an easier way.

Comment: can moment.js accomplish this?

Comment: yes, you can use moment.js to format the date

Comment: or look at [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Comment: What's wrong with `let this_date = new Date("Mon, 16 Nov 2020 09:10:00 GMT")`?

Comment: You may not want to add a massive library like [moment](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=moment@2.29.1) to parse a date if this is a user facing application.

Comment: @Nathan nothing apparently! Thank you. This worked fine and I should have just tried that initially. Just didn't see in any tutorials that date objects could be created this way.

Comment: @Quentin great point didn't realise. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date Does actually advise against passing a string into the constructor. :(

Comment: dang! okay. I will keep looking for another way then

Answer (score 1):

use this to create new date from your string

```
var getDateFrom = array[0].start_date_time;
var setDateTo = new Date(getDateFrom);
//this sets date using string format like you have
```

Answer (score 0):

it is simple you need just to call **Date** with your string.

```
const a=  new Date('Thu, 19 Nov 2020 09:10:00 GMT')
```

or in general :

```
const a=  new Date('start_date_time')
```

you can verify that in console, when you click . after a `a.`
the properties and functions of the **Date** type will appear.